# Writing a javafx textarea to a textfile with linebreaks

Tags: java, javafx, text-files, formatter

So i'm currently trying to save the contents of a javafx textarea to a text file using the formatter class. The problem is that the text just gets saved in one line, without any line breaks.

This is the code i'm  using for the Writing to the textFile

```
 File file = new File(link);
                    Formatter formatter = null;
                    try {
                        formatter = new  Formatter(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    formatter.format(textArea.getText() + "\n");
```

EDIT:
I found the problem: It is the fault of Windows Notepad. When i open the txt file in a other texteditor like notepadd++, it works just fine

Answer (score 2):

do you really need to use the `Formatter` class? I suppose this class produces line separators (only) for the `%n` placeholder (but appears to be ignoring newline characters) in the contents of the format parameter (see also the corresponding [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)):

```
format(String format, Object... args)
// Writes a formatted string to this object's destination using the specified format string and arguments.
```

One solution might be to specify the format string as `"%s%n"` (indicating that you want to format a String, followed by a line break) and pass the TextArea's contents, e.g. `formatter.format("%s%n", textArea.getText())`, if you *really* need to use the formatter.

Otherwise, you may just as well directly output the contents of the textArea to the file via some Writer:

```
FileWriter w = new FileWriter(file);
w.write(textArea.getText());
w.close();
```

Comment: i tried your second idea, but it didn't save the linebreaks again

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the formatter

```
formatter.close();
```

The Formatter output is buffered in memory first. SO you have to close your formatter once you are done.

use finally block for this

```
    try {
        //code
    } catch{
     //code
    }
    finally {
        formatter.close();
    }
```

Comment: i closed it, but i forgot to write in in the Post, Sorry!

Comment: Its working fine here. can  you update code including what the textarea is.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I write the contents of a `TextArea` as follows:

```
byte[] contents = area.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
Files.write(path, contents, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Which saves the contents as a UTF-8 encoded text file. This includes `\n`. Given that I'm working on Linux, I did not check if it actually is `\n\r` or not, my guts tell me it is only `\n`.